# VB.NET How to make 1 sub apply to multiple items?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, contextmenu

I have a lengthy context menu and I wanted to add some visual effect to the items (no, I don't want to make a new renderer), so I just made a MouseEnter and MouseLeave event for one of the list items. 
Now I want to extend this to all of the context menu items without making two separate events for each of the items...

Here is a short example of what I have at the moment:

```
Private Sub NewMenuItems_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NewMenuItem1.MouseEnter, NewMenuItem2.MouseEnter, etc.
    MenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Red
End Sub

Private Sub NewMenuItems_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NewMenuItem1.MouseLeave, NewMenuItem2.MouseLeave
    MenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Cyan
End Sub
```

The only thing that is different for each of the items is what comes before ".Forecolor".
How do I make this work for all items at the same time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all of the instances of `MenuItem` are using the same event handlers then you can distinguish which one actually called it using the `sender` parameter, which should refer to the instance that invoked the event.  So just cast `sender` to a `MenuItem` and that's the one you're looking for.

Note that you should always be careful with casting, of course.  In this case you'd want to make sure that it's only a `MenuItem` which ever calls this handler, otherwise you'll want to put in some error checking/handling with the cast in the event that another object invokes it.